# how to get the process output when using jna and CreateProcessW

Tags: java, jna, createprocess, native-methods

I'm trying to figure out how to read the standard out/err from the 
process I've created with CreateProcessW. I looked at the docs, 
googled and searched this list but I didn't find good pointers/samples 
yet :)

Here's what I came up with so far (it's working fine on windows, it's a relevant snippet from my java code):

```java
Kernel32 kernel32 = (Kernel32) Native.loadLibrary("kernel32", Kernel32.class); 
Kernel32.StartupInfo startupInfo = new Kernel32.StartupInfo(); 
Kernel32.ProcessInfo processInformation = new Kernel32.ProcessInfo(); 

if (!kernel32.CreateProcessW(null, new WString(command), null, null, false, 
  DETACHED_PROCESS, null, new WString(dir.getAbsolutePath()), startupInfo,     
  processInformation)) { 
        throw new IOException("Could not start process. Errno: " +    
            kernel32.GetLastError()); 
} 

kernel32.CloseHandle(processInformation.hProcess); 
kernel32.CloseHandle(processInformation.hThread);
```

So... how can I grab the output from that process? Anyone has done that already and care sharing a sample?

Thanks guys for any help in advance.

Comment: I don't think `CreateProcess` will return an object of process information since the specs says it returns a BOOL value. You should probe into the state of `ProcessInformation` structure this function refers to in its parameters right after it is called. In the specs, it says `lpProcessInformation [out]` as `a pointer to a PROCESS_INFORMATION structure that receives identification information about the new process`. Or, you can use Kernel32's [`GetProcessInformation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh448381%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function with an example.

Comment: Thanks a lot for response! Yeah, I gathered the method itself won't give the output. The StartupInfo contains (among others):

    public HANDLE hStdInput;
    public HANDLE hStdOutput;
    public HANDLE hStdError;

However, I'm not sure how do I map HANDLE to something that can be consumed on the java side. I'd expect it would be some stream I could read on the java side. Also I don't strictly know how to assign those fields correctly...

I'll dig into your suggestions around GetProcessInformation. If you have any other pointers please do reply as I'm pretty green in the area. THANKS again!

Comment: Sorry, it seems that we cannot achieve anything (getting the output) from `ProcessInformation`structure or `GetProcessInformation` function. See the solution I have given below

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To write to a console for a process created with `CreateProcess` function, MSDN suggests to create a child process and use anonymous pipes to redirect child process's standard input and output handles.

[Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Since JNA 3.3.0 Platform hasn't include all the Kernel32 functions we need, we need to provide the required JNA interfaces as follows:  (NOTE JNA 4.0 provides [Kernel32](http://twall.github.io/jna/3.3.0/javadoc/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/Kernel32.html) for you)

**Kernel32.java:**

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.Pointer;
import com.sun.jna.win32.StdCallLibrary;
import com.sun.jna.win32.W32APIFunctionMapper;
import com.sun.jna.win32.W32APITypeMapper;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinBase.SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinBase.STARTUPINFO;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.DWORD;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinBase.PROCESS_INFORMATION;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinNT.HANDLE;

public interface Kernel32 extends StdCallLibrary {

    final static Map<String, Object> WIN32API_OPTIONS = new HashMap<String, Object>() {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        {
            put(Library.OPTION_FUNCTION_MAPPER, W32APIFunctionMapper.UNICODE);
            put(Library.OPTION_TYPE_MAPPER, W32APITypeMapper.UNICODE);
        }
    };

    public Kernel32 INSTANCE = (Kernel32) Native.loadLibrary("Kernel32", Kernel32.class, WIN32API_OPTIONS);

/*
    BOOL WINAPI CreateProcess(
            __in_opt     LPCTSTR lpApplicationName,
            __inout_opt  LPTSTR lpCommandLine,
            __in_opt     LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpProcessAttributes,
            __in_opt     LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes,
            __in         BOOL bInheritHandles,
            __in         DWORD dwCreationFlags,
            __in_opt     LPVOID lpEnvironment,
            __in_opt     LPCTSTR lpCurrentDirectory,
            __in         LPSTARTUPINFO lpStartupInfo,
            __out        LPPROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInformation
            );    
*/
    public boolean CreateProcess(
            String lpApplicationName, 
            String lpCommandLine, 
            SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpProcessAttributes, 
            SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes,
            boolean bInheritHandles,
            DWORD dwCreationFlags,
            Pointer lpEnvironment,
            String lpCurrentDirectory,
            STARTUPINFO lpStartupInfo,
            PROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInformation
            );

    public HANDLE GetStdHandle(DWORD nStdHandle);

    public int GetLastError();
}
```

Then, the main part:

**RunTest.java:**

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.Pointer;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinBase.PROCESS_INFORMATION;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinBase.SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinBase.STARTUPINFO;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.DWORD;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinNT.HANDLE;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinNT.HANDLEByReference;
import com.sun.jna.ptr.IntByReference;


public class RunTest {

    static HANDLEByReference childStdInRead = new HANDLEByReference();
    static HANDLEByReference childStdInWrite = new HANDLEByReference();
    static HANDLEByReference childStdOutRead = new HANDLEByReference();
    static HANDLEByReference childStdOutWrite = new HANDLEByReference();

    static final int HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT = 0x00000001;
    static final int HANDLE_FLAG_PROTECT_FROM_CLOSE = 0x00000002;


    static final int BUFSIZE = 4096;
    static final int GENERIC_READ = 0x80000000;
    static final int FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY = 1;
    private static final int OPEN_EXISTING = 3;
    private static final DWORD STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE = new DWORD(-11);
    private static final int STARTF_USESTDHANDLES = 0x00000100;

    static HANDLE inputFile = null;

    static void createChildProcess(String cmd){
        String szCmdline = cmd;

        PROCESS_INFORMATION processInformation = new PROCESS_INFORMATION();
        STARTUPINFO startupInfo = new STARTUPINFO();
        startupInfo.cb = new DWORD(processInformation.size());
        startupInfo.hStdError = childStdOutWrite.getValue();
        startupInfo.hStdOutput = childStdOutWrite.getValue();
        startupInfo.hStdInput = childStdInRead.getValue();
        startupInfo.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;

        // Create the child process. 
        if (!Kernel32.INSTANCE.CreateProcess(
                null, 
                szCmdline, 
                null, 
                null, 
                true, 
                new DWORD(0x00000020), 
                null, 
                null, 
                startupInfo, 
                processInformation)){
            System.err.println(Kernel32.INSTANCE.GetLastError());
        }
        else {
            com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Kernel32.INSTANCE.WaitForSingleObject(processInformation.hProcess, 0xFFFFFFFF);

            com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Kernel32.INSTANCE.CloseHandle(processInformation.hProcess);
            com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Kernel32.INSTANCE.CloseHandle(processInformation.hThread);
        }
    }

    static void WriteToPipe() 

    // Read from a file and write its contents to the pipe for the child's STDIN.
    // Stop when there is no more data. 
    { 
        IntByReference dwRead = new IntByReference();
        IntByReference dwWritten = new IntByReference(); 
        ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(BUFSIZE);
        Pointer data = Native.getDirectBufferPointer(buf);
        boolean bSuccess = true;

        for (;;) 
        { 
            bSuccess = com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Kernel32.INSTANCE.ReadFile(inputFile, buf, BUFSIZE, dwRead, null);
            if ( ! bSuccess || dwRead.getValue() == 0 ) break; 

            bSuccess = com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Kernel32.INSTANCE.WriteFile(childStdInWrite.getValue(), data.getByteArray(0, BUFSIZE), dwRead.getValue(), dwWritten, null);
            if ( ! bSuccess ) break; 
        } 

        // Close the pipe handle so the child process stops reading. 

        if (!com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Kernel32.INSTANCE.CloseHandle(childStdInWrite.getValue())){ 
            System.err.println(Kernel32.INSTANCE.GetLastError()); 
        }
    }

    static void ReadFromPipe() 

    // Read output from the child process's pipe for STDOUT
    // and write to the parent process's pipe for STDOUT. 
    // Stop when there is no more data. 
    { 
        IntByReference dwRead = new IntByReference();
        IntByReference dwWritten = new IntByReference(); 
        ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(BUFSIZE);
        Pointer data = Native.getDirectBufferPointer(buf);
        boolean bSuccess = true;
        HANDLE hParentStdOut = Kernel32.INSTANCE.GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

        // Close the write end of the pipe before reading from the 
        // read end of the pipe, to control child process execution.
        // The pipe is assumed to have enough buffer space to hold the
        // data the child process has already written to it.

        if (!com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Kernel32.INSTANCE.CloseHandle(childStdOutWrite.getValue())){ 
            System.err.println(Kernel32.INSTANCE.GetLastError()); 
        }

        for (;;) 
        { 
            bSuccess = com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Kernel32.INSTANCE.ReadFile( childStdOutRead.getValue(), buf, BUFSIZE, dwRead, null);
            if( ! bSuccess || dwRead.getValue() == 0 ) break; 

            bSuccess = com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Kernel32.INSTANCE.WriteFile(hParentStdOut, data.getByteArray(0, BUFSIZE), dwRead.getValue(), dwWritten, null);
            if (! bSuccess ) break; 
        } 
    }   
    /**
     * {@link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499(v=vs.85).aspx}
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        if (args.length < 1) {
              System.err.println("Please specify a command.\n");
              System.exit(1);
        }

        if (args.length < 2) {
              System.err.println("Please specify an input file.\n");
              System.exit(1);
        }

        SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES saAttr = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
        saAttr.dwLength = new DWORD(saAttr.size());
        saAttr.bInheritHandle = true;
        saAttr.lpSecurityDescriptor = null;

        // Create a pipe for the child process's STDOUT. 
        if (!com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Kernel32.INSTANCE.CreatePipe(childStdOutRead, childStdOutWrite, saAttr, 0)){
            System.err.println(Kernel32.INSTANCE.GetLastError());
        }

        // Ensure the read handle to the pipe for STDOUT is not inherited.
        if (!com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Kernel32.INSTANCE.SetHandleInformation(childStdOutRead.getValue(), HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0)){
            System.err.println(Kernel32.INSTANCE.GetLastError());;
        }

        // Create a pipe for the child process's STDIN. 
        if (!com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Kernel32.INSTANCE.CreatePipe(childStdInRead, childStdInWrite, saAttr, 0)){
            System.err.println(Kernel32.INSTANCE.GetLastError());
        }

        // Ensure the write handle to the pipe for STDIN is not inherited.
        if (!com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Kernel32.INSTANCE.SetHandleInformation(childStdInWrite.getValue(), HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0)){
            System.err.println(Kernel32.INSTANCE.GetLastError());;
        }

        createChildProcess(args[0]);

        inputFile = com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Kernel32.INSTANCE.CreateFile(
                args[1], 
                GENERIC_READ, 
                0, 
                null, 
                OPEN_EXISTING, 
                FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY, 
                null);

        // Write to the pipe that is the standard input for a child process. 
        // Data is written to the pipe's buffers, so it is not necessary to wait
        // until the child process is running before writing data.

           WriteToPipe(); 
           System.out.println( "\n->Contents of \""+args[1]+"\" written to child STDIN pipe.\n");

        // Read from pipe that is the standard output for child process. 

           System.out.println( "\n->Contents of child process STDOUT:\n\n" + args[1]);
           ReadFromPipe(); 

           System.out.println("\n->End of parent execution.\n");

        // The remaining open handles are cleaned up when this process terminates. 
        // To avoid resource leaks in a larger application, close handles explicitly. 


    }

}
```

The original MSDN program only asks for one argument. But, the modified Runtest java program will need two arguments: (1) the command line; (2) the input file.

Example usage:

```
java -jar RunTest.jar "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre6\\bin\\java.exe -version" "C:\\Documents and Settings\\Administrator\\Desktop\\test.txt"
```

Example output of the program:

```
->Contents of "C:\\Documents and Settings\\Administrator\\Desktop\\test.txt" written to child STDIN pipe.


->Contents of child process STDOUT:

C:\\Documents and Settings\\Administrator\\Desktop\\test.txt
java version "1.6.0_29"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_29-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 20.4-b02, mixed mode, sharing)

->End of parent execution.
```

If you want to see an elaborate version... [WindowsXPProcess.java](http://www.koders.com/java/fid289D621B709F604AC4236BEF49F12AA044CEA8E6.aspx)

Comment: Hey. I really appreciate the thorough answer! Here's my original problem for reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9012639/java-process-inputstream-stuck

Comment: I think you do not need to implement Kernel32. I just downloaded the latest version of JNA (4.0) and it already has a method called Kernel32.CreateProcess. see http://twall.github.io/jna/3.3.0/javadoc/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/Kernel32.html

Comment: The link to `WindowsXPProcess.java` does not work any more.