# Kernel32.INSTANCE.CreateProcess return as String

Tags: java, jna

Here is my code from the jna sample i am try using native code to run cmd command

```
boolean status = Kernel32.INSTANCE.CreateProcess(
                    null,
                    "cmd.exe /c echo here is output",
                    null,
                    null,
                    true,
                    new WinDef.DWORD(0),
                    Pointer.NULL,
                    System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"),
                    startupInfo,
                    processInformation);
```

When i run the code i got this in the Compiler

```
here is output
```

Is any way to store the  Above Output in a string value

Comment: `String output = "here is output";`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get the process output when using jna and CreateProcessW](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8903510/how-to-get-the-process-output-when-using-jna-and-createprocessw)

Comment: it uses old jna version and also i don't see any way to save the output in string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to have a much easier time doing this with [Apache Commons Exec](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/index.html) with the code from [How can I capture the output of a command as a String with Commons Exec?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6295866/how-can-i-capture-the-output-of-a-command-as-a-string-with-commons-exec)

If you need to specifically use JNA for some reason, you can use what @KompjoeFriek posted -- [how to get the process output when using jna and CreateProcessW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8903510/how-to-get-the-process-output-when-using-jna-and-createprocessw)